# Display html page number on web browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a web-based tutorial, with modules that have multiple pages.  I have the page number (xx of yy, e.g. "01 / 12") at the bottom of each page, using an html div and css.  I have a java wrapper, but can't figure out how to get a page number to display, without having to manually update every html file.  The course is structured as "..\L01_CourseOrientation\p01.html", "..|L01_CourseOrientation\p02.html", etc.  Each module has a different number of html files/pages in it, so I want to create a universal java script function that will allow me to display what page I'm currently on out of however many pages are in the module.  This will make it easier for when I have to add or remove pages, I don't have to manually update dozens of pages.

Html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="text_area">Course information here</div>
        <div id="pgnbr">01 / 10</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css:

```
#text_area {
    background: url(557logo1.png) no-repeat center;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 936px;
    height: 556px;
    left: 44px;
    top: 107px;
    z-index: 7;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#pgnbr {
    position: absolute;
    font: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 1px;
    width: 75px;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 890px;
    top: 695px;
}
```

Comment: What kind of server are you running? Personally I would probably use a template engine of some sort to do this. Such as [Markup.js](https://github.com/adammark/Markup.js) for NodeJS, or [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) which comes with Laravel for example.

Answer (score 0):

use window.location.href  to get the current url

then parse the url

```
function ParseUrl(PageURL)
{
PageURL.lastIndexOf("\");
.....
...
return PAGENUMBER;
}
```

then update the page number

document.getElementById("pgnbr").innerHTML =ParseUrl(PageURL);

Comment: This can resolve the current page number, but does not handle the max amount of pages.